# How to resize and move an SDLSurface on Android

Tags: android, android-activity, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to build a project with SDL2 on Android.

My project requirements is to have half of the screen filled with the SDL surface, and the other half with some android buttons.

I tried to edit the standard project to achieve this.

This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/sdl_view"
    tools:context="org.libsdl.app.SDLActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's how I edited SDLActivity:

```
public class SDLActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Log.v("SDL", "onCreate()");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // So we can call stuff from static callbacks
        mSingleton = this;

        // Set up the surface
        mEGLSurface = EGL10.EGL_NO_SURFACE;
        mSurface = new SDLSurface(getApplication());
        mEGLContext = EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT;


        mLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.sdl_view);
        //mLayout = new AbsoluteLayout(this);
        mLayout.addView(mSurface);

        setContentView(mLayout);

        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mSurface.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = 300;
        // Commit the layout parameters
        mSurface.setLayoutParams(lp);

    }
...
}
```

My problem is that I have half of the screen filled with the surface, and the other one white. So, actually, I can't see the TextView I have in the layout.

How can I fix this?